# AEM: Workflow behaves in different ways depending on the DAM path

Tags: java, workflow, aem, assets

AEM: 6.1, author mode

I'm using the Assets API to upload assets to certain paths inside my DAM. This curl command shows how I'm invoking the API:

```
curl -v -i -X POST -F file=@"some-file.pdf" -u admin:admin http://localhost:4502/content/dam/myapp/some/path.createasset.html
```

In a normal execution, above command will create a structure like this in the DAM:

[image]

In the image above, the new asset has 2 folders: renditions and subassets. Renditions is created by the "createasset.html" servlet (look at the path in the curl command). Subassets folder is created by the workflow "DAM Update Asset", which is OOTB.

The problem I'm seeing is, depending on the DAM path I invoke the API with, the subassets folder is not created. And when this happens, I see a lot of exceptions in the logs. Here is an extract of the exceptions:

```
https://pastebin.com/b57cvSZs
```

For example, the API would work for a path like this:

```
/content/dam/myapp/some/path
```

But if the path goes more deep in the tree structure, it won't work:

```
/content/dam/myapp/some/path/something/something2
```

I'm trying to understand why would this happen. I don't see why a different location for the same file would cause all these exceptions.

Comment: The exception that you posted mentions nothing about sub-assets (which are created by the [CreateSubAssetsProcess](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/dam/core/process/CreateSubAssetsProcess.html). Instead it throws an error in the GateKeeperProcess which has the following description in its Javadoc - _This process prevents the asset being updated after the asset got restored. see bug#26535 - Revert version kicks workflow_

Comment: It turned to be that my changes was the cause. I'm new to AEM, and I've been making changes in some workflows. I didn't know AEM keeps like fresh copies of my workflow models and launchers, even if I deploy some other version of them. I had to manually delete all the nodes from CRX, and right after that I started to see some progress.